# Improper removal of tags based on their keys in React js

Tags: reactjs, input, tags, antd

I have an input text box. The value on enter will be populated as tags below that . On removing the tags based on their index , it is not removed as expected . multiple tags are removed on closing a single tag .

Link [codesandbox]: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-chebyshev-iek41

```
class App extends React.Component{
  state={
    text:[],
    tags:[]
  };
  handleSearch = (value) => {
    const tagsMap = [...this.state.tags];
    tagsMap.push(`${value}`.trim());
    this.setState({text:value,tags:tagsMap},()=>console.log(this.state.text))
  }
  onCloseTag = (key) => {
    console.log('Closed', key);
    this.setState({
      tags: this.state.tags.filter((_, index) => index !== key)
    });

  }
  render(){
    const { tags } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <Search
        placeholder="input search text"
        onSearch={(value)=>this.handleSearch(value)}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
      /><br/>
      {tags.map((tag,i) => <Tag key={i} closable onClose={() => this.onCloseTag(i)} color="#f50">{tag}</Tag> )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected : remove one tag on close of that specific tag

Actual : multiple tags are removed on close

Comment: never use index for such operations. rather create an Id of the object and use that to remove the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` did the work. Just pass `e` (event) to `onCloseTag` function.

```
{tags.map((tag,i) => <Tag key={i} closable onClose={(e) => this.onCloseTag(e,i)} color="#f50">{tag}</Tag> )}
```

`onCloseTag` function should be,

```
onCloseTag = (e,key) => {
  e.preventDefault();   //This did the job.
  console.log('Closed', key);
  this.setState({
      tags: this.state.tags.filter((_, index) => index !== key)
  });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f5ehue)

Answer (score 2):

Using the index as the key is `anti-pattern` in ReactJS:

- [React document/Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)
- [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Modify your code you can see why it happens:

```
      {JSON.stringify(tags)}//add this line
      {tags.map((tag,i) => <Tag key={i} closable onClose={() => this.onCloseTag(i)} color="#f50">{tag}</Tag> )}
```

[image: screnshot]

Answer (score 1):

never use index for such operations. rather create an Id of the object and use that to remove the item. Have changed your tags array to an array of objects containing a unique Id for each tag.

```
   handleSearch = (value) => {
      //Add Id to be used for removal later
     const tagsMap = [...this.state.tags,{Id:Math.random(),value}];
      this.setState({text:value,tags:tagsMap},()=>console.log(this.state.text)) 
          }
```

first pass the Id instead of the key and refactored code for using array of ojects instead of array of strings

```
 {tags.map((tag,i) => <Tag key={i} closable onClose={() => this.onCloseTag(tag.Id)} color="#f50">{tag.value}</Tag> )}
```

and then use that Id to remove

```
  onCloseTag = (Id) => {
    console.log('Closed', key);
    this.setState({
      tags: this.state.tags.filter(Tag => Tag.Id!== Id)
    });

  }
```